# Implementing global hotkey in WPF without breaking MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Workflow of my app:

Run -> `LoginPage` -> `MainPage(Hotkey registered)`

Hotkey logic of MainPage:

```cs
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
    RegisterHotKey(handle, 48000, 1, 123);
    Debug.WriteLine("Hotkey Registered");
}
```

Hotkey logic of MainWindow:

```cs
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
}

internal IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == 786)
    {
        int key = ((int)lParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
        int modifierKey = (int)lParam & 0xFFFF;
        if ((modifierKey == 1) && (key == 123)) // Pressed Alt+F12
        {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

I implemented global hotkey in the MainWindow of WPF app using user32.dll. I want to write code displaying a screenshot taken from pressing Alt+PrtScn on the Image control of MainPage when GlobalHotkey is pressed. However, Global hotkey is handled by MainWindow, and I need to modify the source of the Image control. How can I write the proper code(using ViewModel)?

Comment: So are you afraid to use window handle to use global hotkey because it could be contrary to MVVM?

Comment: I'm still learning about MVVM and C#. I'm just confused because MVVM is recommended in WPF.

Comment: IMHO, View's responsibility is to interact with user and receiving user input by global hotkey would be a part of it. That said, the window handle for global hotkey is not necessarily linked to a specific window, you can separate that logic from your MainWindow.

Comment: You need to understand *why* we use MVVM.  It's not sufficient to simply do it because that is what is "recommended."

Comment: If all you're doing is changing a picture then that seems very view orientated. If there's more to do than that you could use bjnding to communicate view to viewmodel. Or weakreferencemessenger. Either could mean your view doesn't have to be viewmodel-aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the hook/event handler should be done in the view (window). It's not different from raising any other event in response to for example a key press or a mouse click. It's your *application logic* that should reside in the view model.

In your hook, you could call a method of the view model, e.g.:

```
internal IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
        viewModel.HandleEvent(msg);

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

So in short, the event is raised in the view but your logic to handle the event is defined in the view model.

MVVM is not about eliminating code from the views. It's about separation of concerns.

Comment: Well, minimizing the code in the Views is a very useful side-effect, and a good indication that you're using MVVM correctly.  But yes, SOC is its primary purpose.  Every bit of code in the View creates some coupling, so the less code there is in the view, the better.

Comment: It depends on the view logic I guess. You may of course move the view-related code out of the actual views to reusable extension methods or attached behaviours. But not to the view models.

Comment: It does.  I'm a pretty strict adherent to MVVM, but in my last project, I wrote one of the modules entirely in code behind, for reasons beyond the scope of this post.  The key is to be disciplined; there are other ways of getting SOC besides MVVM.  Being very good at ordinary object-oriented refactoring certainly helps.

Comment: The view ultimately knows the view model. Regarding coupling, there is no fundamental difference between data binding to a view model's property X in XAML or calling its method Y in the view's code behind. You may perhaps argue that the latter creates a compile-time dependency while the former only creates a runtime dependency, but this is only true for the specific data binding implementation in WPF.